# F13 with normal Western Keyboard and Mac Taken?

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to setup F13 (PrtSc) on my Das Keyboard to trigger Skitch, but Skitch says F13 is taken. I looked all through the keyboard shortcuts menu in the System Prefs and I can find F14-15 but not F13. Any ideas where this is and how to disable it so I can use Skitch?

Comment: belongs to [http://apple.stackexchange.com/](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Phil - It's quite on-topic for Super User

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Services menu items on 10.6 can define keyboard shortcuts that don't show up with the rest of them.  Since the Services menu is context-dependent in 10.6, finding out what shortcuts have been taken that way may be tricky.  (I just discovered this while researching how to write my own service.)